# t-test for means of daily conversion

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design, z-test, ab-test

Let's say I'm a/b testing a new site version and want to know if it improves conversion.

I realize that conversion is a proportion so I would use a Z-test for this.

But then I am thinking - it is not entirely clear to me why I can't compute the daily conversion rate and then take the average of these conversions over the time period of the test, and use a t-test to compare the averages. Is there something wrong with this approach that I am missing?

Comment: Your proposed method should work provided the number of visits to both A and B are relatively equal.  There is a large increase in the Power of the analysis with a larger sample size.  Statistical speaking there is a difference between 1 out of 10 versus 100 out of 1000.

Comment: but is one method better than the other?